# Gas concentrations along the gradient from sea level to deep-sea

Tags: gas-laws, pressure

Studying [scuba diving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scuba_diving)-related phenomenas I thought about how to estimate gases concentration down the sea.

Of course, solubility of gases at, for example, $5$ atm of pressure, can be estimated with Henry's law, i.e

$$S=k\,P_g$$

But this is not the case down the sea, cause there is no gas in equilibrium with sea-water. There should be a way to relate solubility on the deep with the surface pressure, but can't find how.

So, is there any way to estimate gases concentration deep into the sea?

Comment: Gas concentrations down the sea can't be estimated; instead, they must be _measured_. Equilibrium is of no help here, just like I said.

Comment: Yes, and your opinion is valuable @IvanNeretin, but I don't see there is a reason for that. There is no eq but maybe it can be estimated.

Comment: It can't. It is below the equilibrium pressure (and well below it, in fact), but that's about it. You can't tell any more than that from the first principles. Can there be a sea of water not containing any gas at all? Why, sure. Can there be a sea nearly saturated with oxygen? Why, sure. Where is the _real_, actual sea? Someplace between.

Comment: @IvanNeretin There should be something like an exponential decrease...(I'm just joking). If there isn't any valuable answer or opinion I'll remove it, but let me wait.

Comment: Says who? Why an exponential decrease? In fact, there actually **is** a decrease, and probably it can be well approximated by a downward exponent, but the reason for this (if any) lies far away from chemistry.